# In a 100 X 2 matrix, how do divide each element in column 2 by a constant?

Tags: matlab, operation

I have a 100 by 2 matrix.  And I'm trying to figure out how to divide all terms in the second column by a constant.

For example, let's say I have this matrix.

```
[1  2;
3  4;
5  6]
```

I want to divide the 2nd column by 2.

```
[1  2/2;
3  4/2;
5  6/2]
```

So my final matrix will be.

```
[1  1;
3  2;
5  3]
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

If your matrix is M then:

```
 M(:,2)=M(:,2)./2;
```

will divide all terms in the second column by a constant (2). By the way, because the value you divide with is a constant you can also write `/` instead of `./`
If you'd like to assemble a new matrix and not overwrite the first one just write something like this:

```
 A=[M(:,1) M(:,2)./2]
```

Comment: You are right, I was confusing myself with some previous matlab output I had in my command window. I've edited out that line

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how natan 's equations should be read, but I'd multiply the first matrix

```
1  2
3  4
5  6
```

by the matrix

```
1 0
0 .5
```

The resulting matrix is

```
1 1
3 2
5 3
```